# Best practice to return collection as binary from REST API

Tags: rest

I am wondering what the best practice as far as constructing my URLs and as far as delivery to browser might be for my issue. I've browsed a number of posts related to this but none quite fit.

My user has the option to select multiple items and request one pdf of them all (invoices in this case - where I return one PDF with a page for each invoice).

What would be the RESTful approach to this?  My pdf is generated on the fly so there's no resource I can point them to. Also, in most posts that I have seen related to this, it relates to returning a pdf for a single resource as opposed to a collection.

My API looks like this:

```
GET /api/orders // all orders
GET /api/orders/123  //123 order
GET /api/orders/invoice?ids=123,456 // Return a PDF of 2 orders to browser
```

Not very satisfied with this approach. Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

> My pdf is generated on the fly so there's no resource I can point them to.

I don't agree with this. Resource doesn't have to physically exist, it is a logical entity. I like your API.